# Move values in DT table in R shiny towards left

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

In DT table/datatable in R shiny. When there is no data available. There is sentences telling "No data available". Wanted to check if we can move this sentence towards left. Currently it is displayed in the center

can anyone please help?

Below is the part from Rshiny

```
output$table <- DT::renderDT({

    datatable(data2(......)) 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `td.dataTables_empty` CSS.

Outside Shiny, you can do:

```
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(X = numeric(0), Y = numeric(0))

callback <- '$("td.dataTables_empty").css("text-align", "left");'

datatable(dat, callback = JS(callback))
```

This also works inside Shiny (declare `callback` where you want, e.g. at the beginning of the app).
But inside Shiny you can also change the CSS like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(X = numeric(0), Y = numeric(0))

css <- "td.dataTables_empty {text-align: left !important;}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. But where should I declare it. I have edited my question for you

Comment: Hi Stephane. Can you please help me in this??

Comment: @imranp Looks like you don't attempt anything. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks and got it. Sorry